Vertically center inner input with outer button
I have this layout


<div class="container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text">
    <small>Some text</small>
  </div>
  <button>Click</button>
</div>



Given that
<input type="text">
<small>Some text</small>

is the result of rendering a component from a library that I don't have much control over it's style,
I want to know if it's possible to horizontally center the  element with the button element.
I tried doing it with flex and grid but I could not succeed,
Here is the actual code with vuetify component
    <div class="emails-dataset-actions-container">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="searchedDatasetName"
        class="right-gap name-filter-field inline-middle"
        variant="outlined"
        color="primary"
        density="compact"
        :placeholder="$t('filter')"
        @input="onNameFilterInput"
      />
      <v-btn
        class="create-dataset-button"
        style="box-shadow: none"
        color="primary"
        variant="outlined"
        @click="() => openEmailsDatasetEditor()"
        rounded
      >
        <v-icon
          size="17"
          start
        >
          fas fa-plus
        </v-icon>
        {{ $t("emailsDatasets.create") }}
      </v-btn>
    </div>

.emails-dataset-actions-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "input button";
  width: 550px;
}

.name-filter-field {
  grid-area: input;
  width: 250px;
}

.create-dataset-button {
  grid-area: button;
}


and here is the result,
enter image description here

"I tried doing it with flex and grid but I could not succeed," - Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

text-align: center; on .container (?)

Possible with display: grid and subgrid


.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: .25em;
}

.input-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-column: span 2;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  grid-row: 2;
  justify-self: center;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text">
    <small>Some text</small>
  </div>
  <button>Click</button>
</div>




is it possible to apply this to vertically center instead of horizontally ?

Vertically center what?

the input with the button, so they are in the same line, and the small text is under the input

That's not what you asked for but sure - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XWLzRvp
